# python requests: see text of redirect page after post

Tags: python, python-requests, forms, http-post

I'm trying to use requests to query a website for response information from a form post, but I get back different html content when using the site manually (filling out form and clicking submit button) on submitting a form than I get in my `response.text` object when using requests to post to the site.

When posting the form manually, the site redirects back to the form page, with new text (some new `<h#>` and `<ul>` objects) showing below the form. However, with `requests.post`, my  `response.text` object just gives me the content of the page as if I were doing a `requests.get`, suggesting to me the redirect when using the site manually is different from the redirect I get from requests.

Any idea how I can get my `response.text` to match up with what I see using the site manually? Or maybe the response object isn't even what I should use to get that text? My thoughts are maybe the website manually redirects to the same form page as a POST, and requests forces redirect as a GET, and I need to override this feature somehow?

Here's code I'm using:

```
import requests

get_resp = requests.get(url="https://example-site.com")

# It's a Django site so I need to get the csrftoken
csrf_token = get_resp.cookies['csrftoken']

post_resp = requests.post(
    url="https://example-site.com",
    data={"key1": "value1",
          "key2": "value2"},
    headers={"X-CSRFToken": csrf_token},
)

print(post_resp.text)
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You may use [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io) for you problem.

Comment: Well, if it's possible to use requests I'd like to use that. The library I'm using for this project is built on top of requests. Thank you for suggestion though, I'll look into it as alternative.

Comment: When you say you make post form manualy, you mean on the entring the url in the address bar and then hit enter?

Comment: Yeah, I mean I go to the actual web page on my browser, enter data into the form's fields and click the submit button.